# mock a class in python that used by other class

Tags: pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

I am trying to mock a function on a class that calls a function that is in other calls a method of other class as shown below.

```
class check:
    def __init__(self):
        asdad

    def b(self):
        return class_test.MyClass.a()

class MyClass():
    def a():
        return "qwertu"
```

I tried to mock a function "b" of class "check" using Mock from "unittest.mock" and I am able to mock it as shown below

```
def test_mock_class():
    main.check.b = Mock(return_value='mocked value')
    assert main.check.b() == 'mocked value'
```

and it is working as expected.

now i am trying to mock the method of extended class as shown below

```
def test_mock_class():
    class_test.MyClass.a = Mock(return_value='mocked value')
    ob = main.check()
    assert ob.b() == 'mocked value'
```

but it is not working as expected, it says that "qwertu" is not eqaul to "mocked value", but i have already mocked a() method of MyClass, what is the problem.

Comment: The class relationships are defined at loading, ie: before the patch ever occurs.